# ElasticsearchRepository findBy query is returning null when parameter has special characters in it

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, elasticsearch-query

I have an ES collection with following doc schema.

```
public class Address {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String city;
}
```

My repository looks like as follows:

```
public interface NetworkElementsESRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Address, String> {
     Address findByNameAndCity(String name, String city);
}
```

When I run the query **addressRepo.findByNameAndCity(Name,City)**, it returns null when the name parameter has special character(s) (e.g. B00/A3K/24) but returns the result fine when Name has no special characters.

I have gone through the whole documentation for ElasticSearch and ES usage with Spring Boot but all in vain. I am not getting the exact bug as why query is not running.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you may be using the Elasticsearch `text` field for your `name` field, which uses the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) and removes the special char like `/` in your case as shown in the below sample. and then using `[term][1]` query or some other query which doesn't remove the `/` char in your query.

### Analyze API

```
{
    "text": "B00/A3K/24",
    "analyzer" : "standard"
}
```

### Generated tokens

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "b00",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "a3k",
            "start_offset": 4,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "24",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

**Above is based on whatever information you provided and if you can provide your index mapping and search query in JSON format, I can confirm this or tell you the exact reason.**

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Since I am new to ES,  I am still confused if this ElasticsearchRepository from Spring data uses standard analyzer by default ? If yes, then do i need to write a customer analyzer for this ?

Comment: thank you. just fyi, my json query needs to look like this `{ "query" : { "bool" : { "must" : [ { "query_string" : { "query" : "?", "fields" : [ "name" ] } }, { "query_string" : { "query" : "?", "fields" : [ "city" ] } } ] } }}`

Comment: @akshit, you are using query string which is not recommended and instead you should use the boolean query, but please don't mix up things here, as it would not be helpful for communities, can you please ask a seprate question and as suggested mark this as answer and ping your new question link in comment, I will have a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857245/need-to-write-a-custom-analyzer-for-elasticsearchrepository-findby-query

Comment: @akshit, can u please do the needful, please understand that we take out quite some time to help the community and its importance for the community to recognize the answers and this motivates us to go extra mile