# Need to write a custom analyzer for ElasticsearchRepository findBy query

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an ES collection with following doc schema.

`

```
public class Address {
@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private String type;
private String city;
}
```

`
My repository looks like as follows:

```
public interface NetworkElementsESRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Address, String> {
Address findByNameAndCity(String name, String city);}
```

I need to fetch all addresses with name= "B00/A3K/24" in a particular city using following Query.
**addressRepo.findByNameAndCity(Name,City)** . I am not able to fetch the required addresses since **name** field has special characters ('/') and standard Analyzer seems to break the search string into different token. I need help with the custom Analyzer for  ElasticsearchRepository.

Comment: @opster-elasticsearch-ninja

Answer (score 0):

First you need to either create the analyzer [in Elasticsearch yourself](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/analysis-custom-analyzer.html), or by providing a settings file when creating the index with Spring Data Elasticsearch.

If you always need the custom analyzer for this field you can specify the analyzer in the `@Field` annotation you put on the `name` property either with `analyzer` or with `searchAnalyzer`.

If you only need the analyzer for the search with the repository, you should create a repository method annotated with `@Query` and add your custom query  there.

See the [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/specify-analyzer.html#specify-search-query-analyzer) how such a query is built and [Spring Data Elasticsearch docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query) for the use of the `@Query` annotation.